# Can Visual Studio debug Go plugins?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have a Go project that consists of a command line tool and some Go plugins.  I have a build script that builds the CLI, and then goes into a plugins directory and compiles each plugin with the `-buildmode=plugin` option.  I would like to figure out if `launch.json` can be configured to selectively pass the `buildmode` flag.

If I pre-build the plugins and then run the debugger on just the CLI tool, the plugins won't load because they were "built with different version of package X".

I created a task in `tasks.json` to call my build script, and added that task as a `preLaunchTask` for my debug session, but that's not doing the trick.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x 
go build ./cmd/...
cd plugins
for DIR in `find . ! -path . -type d`
do
    go build -buildmode=plugin $DIR/*.go
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want add debug state into .so file

```
go build -gcflags "all=-N -l" -x -v -buildmode=plugin -o plugin/plugin.so plugin/plugin.go
```

But when you want to build in production, please ignore those options.

```
go build -buildmode=plugin -o plugin/plugin.so plugin/plugin.go
```

More details [here](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1628)